# Error using boolean results in new method - expects string, found boolean

Tags: java, if-statement, compilation, boolean

I have created some methods in Java to test the results of a string based on length, characters and digits. However I also need to create a new method to check all those results and produce a boolean result based on if they were all true. But I'm not sure I'm calling the other methods correctly within my IF/ELSE loop and when I compile I'm getting an error stating that it's expecting a String result, but found Boolean. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

The code for the new method is currently:

```
public boolean isValidAccountNum(String s)
{      
  if ( isValidLength(true) && isValidStart(true) && hasValidDigits(true) ){
        return true;
     } else
     {
        return false;
     }
}
```

The other methods are:

```
public boolean isValidLength(String s)
{
  accountNum = s;
  int accountInt = s.length();

  if(accountInt == 6){
     return true;
  } 
  else {
     return false;
  }
}


public boolean isValidStart(String s)
{
  if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0))){
     return true;
  } 
  else {
     return false;
  }
}

public boolean hasValidDigits(String s)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
     if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))){
        return false;
     } else
     {
        return true;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your methods are supposed to receive your `s` `String` as a parameter, not a `boolean` . i.e `if ( isValidLength(s) && isValidStart(s) && hasValidDigits(s) )`

Comment: Always post the error logs if available

Comment: "Any ideas where I'm going wrong?" Your compiler knows, and it tells you exactly where.

Comment: That appears to have worked @Berger thanks! I understand the error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. isValidLength(true) && isValidStart(true) && hasValidDigits(true), these methods have no boolean in their parameters.
2. The answer of the question is:

Changing this:

```
if(isValidLength(true) && isValidStart(true) && hasValidDigits(true)) {}
```

To this:

```
if(isValidLength(s) && isValidStart(s) && hasValidDigits(s)) {}
```

or

```
return isValidLength(s) && isValidStart(s) && hasValidDigits(s);
```

Comment: Maybe mention that `return isValidLength(s) && isValidStart(s) && hasValidDigits(s);` suffices.

Comment: Yeah, I used if...else statements, We can use return which is a one line code, right. Small lines, easier to read, small file sizes.